# Regexpr which excludes groups if they are precedeeded by curly brackets and only matches text within the first section of the bracket

Tags: python, regex, wikitext

I'm writing a Python script to parse Wikipedia articles, and part of that process is parsing links. I'm trying to write a regular expression that matches in this way:

- `[[:Category:Anarchism by country|Anarchism by country]]` -> `:Category:Anarchism by country`
- `[[Squatting|squat]]` -> `Squatting`
- `[[File:Jarach and Zerzan.JPG|thumb|Lawrence Jarach (left) and [[John Zerzan]] (right)` -> `John Zerzan`
- `* {{cite book |last=Avrich |first=Paul |author-link=Paul Avrich |title=[[Anarchist Voices: An Oral History of Anarchism in America]] |year=1996 |publisher=[[Princeton University Press]] |isbn=978-0-691-04494-1` -> Unmatched, begins with `* {{` (citation)

I've reached `\[\[([^|\]]+)(?:\|[^|\]]+)?\]\]` which works in 3 of the above examples, but in the citation it matches the title and the publisher. I know (I think) I need a negative lookahead to prevent any matches in the last example. I'm very bad with regex however, so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Won't it suffice to exclude those not being preceded by an equal sign? Like this: [`(?<!=)`...](https://regex101.com/r/cOyGPU/1) if not, you can use [The Trick](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick) -> match what you don't want but *capture* what you need: [`\* {{.*|(capture this)`](https://regex101.com/r/g6EmQ4/1). You will need to remove empty matches from the result ([Python demo at ideone](https://ideone.com/zcAk43)).

Answer (score 1):

Wikitext is quite complicated and should not be parsed with regexes alone. Instead, use a full-fledged parser, such as [`mwparserfromhell`](https://pypi.org/project/mwparserfromhell):

```py
import mwparserfromhell as mph

def get_links_outside_of_templates(text):
  tree = mph.parse(text)
  # Lazily filter out all top-level links
  links = tree.ifilter_wikilinks(recursive = False)
    
  for link in links:
    if link.title.startswith('File'):
      # If this is a File link, recursively parse its "text".
      yield from get_links_outside_of_templates(link.text)
    else:
      yield link.title

print([*get_links_outside_of_templates(text)])
```

For the following wikitext (partly generated by ChatGPT):

```
'''Squatting''' may refer to [[Squatting|squat]], the act of occupying an abandoned or unused property without legal permission.

== Foo ==

[[File:Jarach and Zerzan.JPG|thumb|Lawrence Jarach (left) and [[John Zerzan]] (right)]]

Lorem ipsum dolor sit [[amet]], consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum interdum, neque nec aliquet venenatis, tortor erat commodo nulla, id imperdiet mi urna eget nunc.

== References ==
* {{cite book
  |last=Avrich |first=Paul |author-link=Paul Avrich
  |title=[[Anarchist Voices: An Oral History of Anarchism in America]]
  |year=1996 |publisher=[[Princeton University Press]]
  |isbn=978-0-691-04494-1
  }}

[[:Category:Anarchism by country|Anarchism by country]]
```

...it outputs:

```py
['Squatting', 'John Zerzan', 'amet', ':Category:Anarchism by country']
```

Unfortunately, `mwparserfromhell` [doesn't recognize namespaces](https://mwparserfromhell.readthedocs.io/en/latest/limitations.html), so you will have to check for `File` links on your own if you were to use it. I use a crude `.startswith('File')` in the function above, but you might want to make a better check, since namespace names are case-insensitive: `file` and `fIlE` are both valid and means the same as `File`.